# Find a value of a cell next to the max value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, vlookup, maxifs

I have a sheet with 3 columns: Employee, Role, Start Date

Each employee has multiple records (his history in the company).

I have a list of all the employees (distinct list) and I want to have a column of the current role for each employee - which means the role of the max date for each employee. I was trying vlookup, and ={max(if...} approaches but couldn't get it right.

Here is a screenshot of an example. As you can see I know how to get the latest date (max) but I can't find a way to get the relevant role for that date.

[image]

Comment: We'll have to see at least some sample data and the formula you've tried in order to help you. Without understanding the data layout better, it's impossible to give an example solution.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT, I have added a screenshot with my current status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An Array Formula**

Select cell `I2` and since this is an **array formula**, you paste the formula into the formula bar and hold down the left **ALT** and **SHIFT** keys and then press **ENTER**.

```
=INDEX(B$2:B$45,MATCH(G2&H2,A$2:A$45&C$2:C$45,0))
```

The formula will look like this in the formula bar:

```
{=INDEX(B$2:B$45,MATCH(G2&H2,A$2:A$45&C$2:C$45,0))} 'Do NOT use this!!!
```

with the **curly braces** indicating that it is an **array formula**.